# Using geography::STGeomFromText for WKT

Tags: sql-server-2012, geography, qgis, wkt

I'm trying to import UK postcode zones from WKT to SQLServer 2012. Most are fine but there's a few that produce an very large polygon (best I can explain it).

When using QGIS the WKT below displays as it should.

`MULTIPOLYGON (((-2.255068 53.669782,
-2.262690 53.651819,
-2.276995 53.676325,
-2.255068 53.669782)))`

but when using geography::STGeomFromText(#above WKT#, 4326) the spatial results window shows a grid filled with a square polygon not the area displayed in QGIS.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer. If the co-ordinates are reversed the polygon displays as it should. I guess my original data had some polygons that were reversed.

.ReorientObject() does this automatically